# Matplotlib FuncAnimation Bad Video Quality

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I always save the animations produced by `FuncAnimation` as `.mp4` videos on my MacBook running Big Sur and the videos all look good. However today the exported videos' quality suddenly decreased. When I plotted a single frame, it looked fine, but the exported video of combined frames displayed a bad quality in the last several frames.

```
f = 30
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, _update_animation, interval=1000/24, frames=f, blit=False, init_func=_init_animate)
ani.save('animations/'+savename+'.mp4', writer=animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=24), dpi=500)
```

Here is a sample frame that's half okay, half bad:

[image: sample frame]

Update: After changing the video format from `.mp4` to `.mov`

```
f = 30
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, _update_animation, interval=1000/24, frames=f, blit=False, init_func=_init_animate)
ani.save('animations/'+savename+'.mov', writer=animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=24), dpi=500)
```

the exported video looks fine, but using `.mp4` still causes the bad quality.